# Use module Set Ocaml

Tags: set, ocaml

I am creating a program that uses a grammar and see if this grammar is LL (1). I want to use the module Set, but I have no idea how to proceed, of course, the type of the elements of the set will char, can you help?

Answer (score 3):

This answer assumes that you already know how to determine if a grammar is LL (1), and are merely looking for help on the specific usage of the Objective Caml `Set` module.

The standard library `Set` provides a functor that lets you construct your own set module, adapted for your specific needs. You need to provide a module that describes the type of elements inside the set, and a comparison function that follows the same convention as [`compare`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.OrderedType.html) : `compare a b = 0` if `a = b`, `compare a b < 0` if `a < b` and so on. For characters, this would be:

```
module OrderedChar = struct
  type t = char
  let compare = compare
end

module CharSet = Set.Make(OrderedChar)
```

The `CharSet` module above has the [interface described in the documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.S.html). The gist of it is that sets are immutable values (like lists), so the module provides you with functions that create a new set from an existing set by adding or removing elements:

```
let a  = CharSet.add    'a' CharSet.empty 
let ab = CharSet.add    'b' a
let b  = CharSet.remove 'a' ab
(* /* a, b and ab are three sets containing respectively {a}, {b} and {ab} */ *)
```

Access to elements of a set happens mostly through existence queries and through iteration:

```
assert (CharSet.mem 'a' ab) 
assert (not (CharSet.mem 'c' b))

CharSet.iter print_char ab 
(* /* Prints 'ab' : follows the order defined by your 'compare' function */ *)
```

Comment: I don't know. Probably not. Does your algorithm require you to store grammars in a set?

Comment: FYI, OCaml's standard library has a `Char` module that conforms to the interface used by Set and Map: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Char.html