# OCaml - how to keep pair of int + my own type in set

Tags: set, ocaml

I would like to  keep in set:

```
( int * int * (my_own_type) )
```

And I want elements wolud be compared by (int * int) - the my_own_set has no influence on order. Only thing that I need is searching element in fast time.

How to do it?

Comment: maybe you want a `Map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a module which does the comparison you want (adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4277832):

```
module MyTypeOrdered = struct
  type t = int * int * (my_own_type)
  let compare (x1, y1, _) (x2, y2, _) = compare (x1, y1) (x2, y2)
end

module MyTypeSet = Set.Make(MyTypeOrdered)
```

With maps it's very similar

```
module IntInt = struct
  type t = int * int
  let compare = compare
end

module MyTypeMap = Map.Make(IntInt)
```

or simply

```
module MyTypeMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int * int let compare = compare end)
```

Comment: So should I write my own comparison? What rules are connected with comparison ?

Comment: Quoting the linked answer: "compare a b = 0 if a = b, compare a b < 0 if a < b and so on".

Comment: If I can find the element in set in fast time ? I mean that find return object, in this case let (a,b, my_object) = set.find (a,b)         I would like to search by pair

Comment: Then you need a Map, not a Set.

Comment: How to create Map of (int * int, my_own_typ)  ?

Comment: Edited to include Map